# Cocoa Touch : A method each time view is shown?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller

there is a method called viewDidLoad that execute a code when the view is loaded is there a method that do the samething but each time the view is shown?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [viewWillAppear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16) or [viewDidAppear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW17).

Comment: @Chris, thanks for adding the links.  The docs are always a good place to start looking.

Comment: This may be obvious but...
viewWillAppear: the view has not yet been added to the window, good place to add subviews.
viewDidAppear: the view has already been added to the window.